# Remover imagens que não estejam presentes na base de dados

Tags: php, sql

Eu comecei a trabalhar num site já feito por um antigo programador que tem uma página de inserção e remoção de imagens. No entanto, ele quando remove, só tira da base de dados deixando a imagem lá, ou seja, fica a ocupar espaço. Já passaram 2 anos desde a criação daquela página e muitas imagens foram apagadas.

Posso fazer um loop de cada dado da base de dados e depois comparar os ficheiros que não existem na pasta?

Comment: cria uma pasta para imagens que ainda estão sendo usadas, no loop da busca vc copia a imagem pra essa nova pasta, vc vai ter uma pasta com todas imagens e outra apenas com as que estao em uso

Comment: Irei tentar isso, vou fazer um backup porque são mais de 2000 fotografias

Comment: isso, faz um backup de segurança

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tive o mesmo problema que você. Tenho um código feito por mim pronto em PDO e Mysql, vou deixar aqui para sua base lógica. Tentarei explicar o máximo possível. (Não irei incluir linhas de código como conexão com banco de dados e etc, pois acho desnecessário).

---

## > Primeiro

As minhas fotos eram salvas por um código gerado automaticamente, que ficava em meu banco de dados num campo chamado ***codigo***.  Ou seja, no banco de dados eu tinha o ***código (ex: 123456)*** e na pasta eu tinha a imagem salva com o ***código.extensão (ex: 123456.png)***.

Além disso, eu renomeei a minha pasta original com as fotos para ***"pastaAntiga"*** e criei uma pasta chamada ***"pastaNova"***, onde ficarão as imagens que estão sim presentes no meu banco de dados.

---

## > Segundo

Partindo para a programação.
Eu busquei todos os registros da minha tabela num ***while*** e, para cada um deles, copiei a imagem com o mesmo código da pasta antiga para a pasta nova usando a função [copy()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.copy.php) do php. Não me preocupei em segurança, pois eu iria fazer isto localmente e depois removeria o recurso. Ou seja, ninguém teria acesso.

---

## > Mãos à obra

```
<?php
include("./conexao.php");
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM fotos");
$sql->execute();
while($imagem = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $imagemOriginal = "./pastaAntiga/".$imagem['codigo'].".png"; //caminho da imagem na pasta original
  $imagemCopia = "./pastaNova/".$imagem['codigo'].".png"; //caminho onde será salvo
  if (copy($imagemOriginal,$imagemCopia)) { // função copy(copiarDe,copiarPara)
    echo "Imagem de código: ".$imagem['codigo']." copiada com sucesso!"; //mensagem caso a imagem seja copiada
    echo "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Erro ao copiar imagem de código: ".$imagem['codigo']; // mensagem caso a imagem não seja copiada
  }
}
?>
```

---

Espero que te ajude!

@edit: lembre-se de fazer um backup antes! Fotos são sempre importantes. Mesmo depois de feito isso tudo, eu não apaguei meu arquivo de backup, porque nunca se sabe quando irá precisar!